# How can I number headings of sections on separate pages?

Tags: html, css, css-counter

I am building a website that contains a document for assigned project. I want to separate each section on its own page (so there's `index.html` containing project assignment, `introduction.html` contains initial informations about the subject and approach I'm gonna use to cover the topic, `theory.html` contains the deeper look into theory behind the subject, etc.) I'm making it as a static website, so it's pure HTML/CSS, with no PHP or JavaScript. But I'm looking for a way to automatically number the sections based on the order of the pages. This is the full page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="cs-CZ">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>ZBK — Semestrální projekt | POL0423</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css" media="screen and (max-width: 700px)" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="logo"><img src="img/fei_cz.png" alt="VŠB-TUO FEI logo" /></div>
            <div class="head">
                <h1 class="predmet">Základy bezpečnosti v komunikacích</h1>
                <h2 class="autor">Marek Poláček (POL0423)</h2>
                <nav><a href="/~pol0423/">Zpět na hlavní stranu</a></nav>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="content" data-section-number="1">
                <h1>Zadání</h1>
                <p class="zadani">Bezpečnost ve 4G a 5G mobilních sítích &ndash; popis zabezpečovacích mechanismů, detailní průzkum možných útoků, analýza proveditelnosti popsaných útoků a jejich složitost.</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>Úkolem je popsat zabezpečovací mechanismy mobilních sítí 4G a 5G, robustnost proti poškození dat a jejich bezpečnosti, prozkoumat možné vektory útoků a analyzovat jejich proveditelnost a složitost.</li>
                    <li>Součástí dokumentu bude detailní popis možných útoků, rizik z nich vyplývajících, a detailní analýza složitosti a proveditelnosti popsaných útoků a zhodnocení, zda má takový útok cenu provádět.</li>
                    <li>Cílem je poskytnout údaje o robustnosti mobilních komunikačních sítí a jejich bezpečnosti pro koncové uživatele.</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar">
                <div class="sidebar__content">
                    <h1 class="toc__title">Obsah</h1>
                    <ol class="toc">
                        <li><a href="index.html" aria-current="true">Zadání</a></li>
                        <li><a href="uvod.html">Úvod</a></li>
                        <li><a href="teorie.html">Teoretický rozbor</a>
                            <ol>
                                <li><a href="teorie.html#sec1">Sekce 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="teorie.html#sec2">Sekce 2</a></li>
                            </ol>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="zaver.html">Závěr</a></li>
                        <li><a href="literatura.html">Literatura</a></li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <strong>Základy bezpečnosti v komunikacích:</strong> Bezpečnost ve 4G a 5G mobilních sítích &ndash; popis zabezpečovacích mechanismů, detailní průzkum možných útoků, analýza proveditelnosti popsaných útoků a jejich složitost.
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

(Ignore the Czech language texts in it, the layout is important) For this, I have set up a CSS for desktop and mobile (responsive design). It's a very simple design, I don't aim for an overwhelmingly complex eye candy, I need to deliver content, so it needs to be as lightweight as possible, but at the same time actually nice looking. Which is why I opted for pure HTML/CSS instead of generative frameworks like Bootstrap.

The part of CSS for which I'm looking for an answer is this:

```css
.content[data-section-number] {
    counter-reset: section calc(attr(data-section-number) - 1);
    counter-reset: subsection;

    & h1 {
        counter-increment: section;
        counter-reset: subsection;
        position: relative;

        &::before {
            content: counter(section);
            left: -3rem;
            position: absolute;
            opacity: 0.6;
            transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
        }

        &:hover::before {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }

    & h2 {
        counter-increment: subsection;
        position: relative;

        &::before {
            content: counter(section) "." counter(subsection);
            left: -3rem;
            position: absolute;
            opacity: 0.6;
            transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
        }

        &:hover::before {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Demo:

```css
.content[data-section-number] {
  counter-reset: section calc(attr(data-section-number) - 1);
  counter-reset: subsection;
  & h1 {
    counter-increment: section;
    counter-reset: subsection;
    position: relative;
    &::before {
      content: counter(section);
      left: -3rem;
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0.6;
      transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    }
    &:hover::before {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  & h2 {
    counter-increment: subsection;
    position: relative;
    &::before {
      content: counter(section) "." counter(subsection);
      left: -3rem;
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0.6;
      transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    }
    &:hover::before {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="cs-CZ">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>ZBK — Semestrální projekt | POL0423</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css" media="screen and (max-width: 700px)" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="logo"><img src="img/fei_cz.png" alt="VŠB-TUO FEI logo" /></div>
    <div class="head">
      <h1 class="predmet">Základy bezpečnosti v komunikacích</h1>
      <h2 class="autor">Marek Poláček (POL0423)</h2>
      <nav><a href="/~pol0423/">Zpět na hlavní stranu</a></nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="content" data-section-number="1">
      <h1>Zadání</h1>
      <p class="zadani">Bezpečnost ve 4G a 5G mobilních sítích &ndash; popis zabezpečovacích mechanismů, detailní průzkum možných útoků, analýza proveditelnosti popsaných útoků a jejich složitost.</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Úkolem je popsat zabezpečovací mechanismy mobilních sítí 4G a 5G, robustnost proti poškození dat a jejich bezpečnosti, prozkoumat možné vektory útoků a analyzovat jejich proveditelnost a složitost.</li>
        <li>Součástí dokumentu bude detailní popis možných útoků, rizik z nich vyplývajících, a detailní analýza složitosti a proveditelnosti popsaných útoků a zhodnocení, zda má takový útok cenu provádět.</li>
        <li>Cílem je poskytnout údaje o robustnosti mobilních komunikačních sítí a jejich bezpečnosti pro koncové uživatele.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="sidebar__content">
        <h1 class="toc__title">Obsah</h1>
        <ol class="toc">
          <li><a href="index.html" aria-current="true">Zadání</a></li>
          <li><a href="uvod.html">Úvod</a></li>
          <li><a href="teorie.html">Teoretický rozbor</a>
            <ol>
              <li><a href="teorie.html#sec1">Sekce 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="teorie.html#sec2">Sekce 2</a></li>
            </ol>
          </li>
          <li><a href="zaver.html">Závěr</a></li>
          <li><a href="literatura.html">Literatura</a></li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <strong>Základy bezpečnosti v komunikacích:</strong> Bezpečnost ve 4G a 5G mobilních sítích &ndash; popis zabezpečovacích mechanismů, detailní průzkum možných útoků, analýza proveditelnosti popsaných útoků a jejich složitost.
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

The issue is that when I change the `data-section-number` to a higher number than `1`, it doesn't work. My guess is the `attr()` function doesn't work anywhere else than in `content` property (which is only used for `::before` and `::after` pseudoelements). But I can't simply put that into the content of the heading, because that actually takes the attribute from the selected element, not from parents. So I can't use solution like `content: attr(data-section-number)`, it simply won't work either. I also tried to set up a local CSS variable and using that, but that didn't work either.

Do you have any idea on how I could acomplish it, ideally without the aid of JavaScript? I really don't like to use JavaScript, it's anything but lightweight, and I'm aiming for a fast loading time.

This is essentially what I'm aiming for:
[image: Website screenshot]

Notice the cursor there, that's what I'm looking for. This is the number I want to be using the section number value I specified in the data attribute.

Comment: @DavidThomas Thank you. So it's basically an experimental feature only working in some browsers (Chrome therefore doesn't support it), which gives me hope it might be usable? That's interesting. But I need it until December when I need to present the assignment, and as I said, I want to avoid using Javascript as much as possible.

Comment: Are your "pages" all different HTML files (I assume so, given the mention of `theory.html` etc), or are they different sections in the *same* web-page? If they're in different documents, then there's no point complicating things and you may as well just put `1`, `2`... in the HTML, since there's nothing for a CSS counter to really count.

Comment: Yes, those are separate HTML files. The thing is however I don't want the numbers to be part of the DOM. Pseudoelements are not selectable, I don't want the section numbers to be selected. And I don't want to use `style=""` attributes to override the numbering, which is why I opted in for the data attribute. But I might as well fall back to that option.

Comment: Yep, that seemed to do the trick. I'm gonna wait with posting this as the definitive answer until someone comes up with a better idea. But yeah, that seems to do the trick. `style="counter-reset: section <section number starting from 0>"`

Comment: Have you considered [`user-select: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) on the element in which the number appears? There are various approaches - including using the `content` property of the element, which allows it to be non-selectable by default in a pseudo-element - depending on your requirements.

Comment: No? Didn't even know that was a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `counter-reset` to reset the counter with the direct style declaration for that specific section:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="cs-CZ">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>ZBK — Semestrální projekt | POL0423</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css" media="screen and (max-width: 700px)" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="logo"><img src="img/fei_cz.png" alt="VŠB-TUO FEI logo" /></div>
            <div class="head">
                <h1 class="predmet">Základy bezpečnosti v komunikacích</h1>
                <h2 class="autor">Marek Poláček (POL0423)</h2>
                <nav><a href="/~pol0423/">Zpět na hlavní stranu</a></nav>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="content" style="counter-reset: section 0;">
                <h1>Zadání</h1>
                <p class="zadani">Bezpečnost ve 4G a 5G mobilních sítích &ndash; popis zabezpečovacích mechanismů, detailní průzkum možných útoků, analýza proveditelnosti popsaných útoků a jejich složitost.</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>Úkolem je popsat zabezpečovací mechanismy mobilních sítí 4G a 5G, robustnost proti poškození dat a jejich bezpečnosti, prozkoumat možné vektory útoků a analyzovat jejich proveditelnost a složitost.</li>
                    <li>Součástí dokumentu bude detailní popis možných útoků, rizik z nich vyplývajících, a detailní analýza složitosti a proveditelnosti popsaných útoků a zhodnocení, zda má takový útok cenu provádět.</li>
                    <li>Cílem je poskytnout údaje o robustnosti mobilních komunikačních sítí a jejich bezpečnosti pro koncové uživatele.</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar">
                <div class="sidebar__content">
                    <h1 class="toc__title">Obsah</h1>
                    <ol class="toc">
                        <li><a href="index.html" aria-current="true">Zadání</a></li>
                        <li><a href="uvod.html">Úvod</a></li>
                        <li><a href="teorie.html">Teoretický rozbor</a>
                            <ol>
                                <li><a href="teorie.html#sec1">Sekce 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="teorie.html#sec2">Sekce 2</a></li>
                            </ol>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="zaver.html">Závěr</a></li>
                        <li><a href="literatura.html">Literatura</a></li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <strong>Základy bezpečnosti v komunikacích:</strong> Bezpečnost ve 4G a 5G mobilních sítích &ndash; popis zabezpečovacích mechanismů, detailní průzkum možných útoků, analýza proveditelnosti popsaných útoků a jejich složitost.
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

The idea is to have `section 0` to be whatever number was the previous page. If it is the first page, it is literally `section 0`. If the previous page was number 5, it is going to be `section 5`. The correct number will always be that number + 1, which is what the counter increment does.